# boost::bind not saving partial arguments when stored

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-bind

I'm trying to make a boost::bind call and save value of passed argument in boost::function and I stumbled upon case I can't explain:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
using callback = boost::function<void (int, std::shared_ptr<T>)>;

class work
{
public:
    int value;
};


void job_callback(int v, std::shared_ptr<int> work)
{
    *work = v;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(10));
    boost::bind(job_callback, _1, a)(1); // compiles and works with 1 arg, *a is 1
    callback<int> call = boost::bind(job_callback, _1, a); // compiles
    call(2, a); // compiles and works with 2 args, *a is 2

    call(3); // does not compile with 1 arg

    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why `boost::bind(job_callback, _1, a)(1)` works, even though only one argument is provided to the resulting functor - so the second argument is passed through - but `call(3)` doesn't compile with the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:761:17: note: boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::result_type boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::operator()(T0, T1) const [with R = void; T0 = int; T1 = std::shared_ptr<int>; boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::result_type = void]
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:761:17: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Is the return type from that `boost::bind` call not `boost::function<void (int, shared_ptr<int>)>` but something else, something that stores the value of the second argument? If so, what is it?

Comment: If you have an option, maybe it's worth trying to use std::bind and std::function in c++11 instead of the boost version.

Comment: @TingL I already use boost heavily and depend on it, also the C++11 support is shady on some of the platforms I'm targeting. Nevertheless, C++11 std::function and std::bind produce the same results in this case.

Comment: @Marcin: Your assumption is correct. The bind will return a `boost::function<void(int)>`. The shared_ptr will be stored within the function object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `boost` and `std` `{bind,function}` produce the same problem. I will use `std` version for discussion. I think the problem is with the assignment to function object.

```
callback<int> call = boost::bind(job_callback, _1, a); // compiles
```

It compiles but is incorrect because `callback<int> == function<void (int,xxx)>`. This is not the right signature because one of the two parameters has been fixed to `a`.

But what's really confusing here is probably why the `function` object should accept the `bind` result when it is not the of the right arity? I think that's maybe related to the flexibility introduced in `std::bind` to handle extra parameters. I suspect this happens in boost as well. But I am not 100% sure on this. I never understand why `bind` should tolerate incorrect number of parameters.

The correct usage is to

```
function<void (int)> call = std::bind(job_callback, _1, a); //also compiles
```

Code using std::{function,bind}

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

template <class T>
using callback = std::function<void (int, std::shared_ptr<T>)>;

class work
{
public:
    int value;
};


void job_callback(int v, std::shared_ptr<int> work)
{
    *work = v;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(10));
    std::bind(job_callback, _1, a)(1); // compiles and works with 1 arg, *a is 1
    //callback<int> call = std::bind(job_callback, _1, a); // compiles
    function<void (int)> call = std::bind(job_callback, _1, a); //also compiles
    //call(2, a); // compiles and works with 2 args, *a is 2

    call(3); // does not compile with 1 arg

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might be worth demonstrating `call(7, std::shared_ptr<int>())` with the original code also modifies `*a` -- that on the `call(2,a)` line, the `a` is a red herring.